# How can I format Ruby arguments/hashes in Vim?

Tags: vim, ruby

I'd like to be able to easily formatting Ruby code from within Vim.

If I have a **method with a hash argument**

```
foobar(foo: "FOO", bar: "BAR")
```

How can I turn it into

```
foobar(
    foo: "FOO",
    bar: "BAR"
)
```

Or, if I have a **normal hash**

```
foobar = { foo: "FOO", bar: "BAR" }
```

Into this

```
foobar = {
    foo: "FOO",
    bar: "BAR"
}
```

How can I achieve this with Vim? Do I need a plugin of some sort?

Answer (score 6):

The following macro works in both cases:

```
qq             " start recording in register q
$              " jump to the last character on the line, a ) or a }
v%             " select from here to the opening ( or {, inclusive
loh            " shrink the selection
c              " remove selection and enter insert mode
<CR><CR><Up>   " open the (){} and put the cursor in between
<C-r>"         " insert the content of default register
<Esc>          " go back to normal mode
:s/,/,\r/g<CR> " replace every , with itself followed by a newline
:'[,']norm ==  " format the whole thing
q              " stop recording
```

Hit `@q` over `foobar(foo: "FOO", bar: "BAR")` to get:

```
foobar(
    foo: "FOO",
    bar: "BAR"
)
```

and over `foobar = { foo: "FOO", bar: "BAR" }` to get:

```
foobar = {
    foo: "FOO",
    bar: "BAR"
}
```

EDIT

While this macro is most likely to be saved across sessions, it's very easy to overwrite it. Fortunately, it's very easy to convert it into a mapping and keep it in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <F6> $v%lohc<CR><CR><Up><C-r>"<Esc>:s/,/,\r/g<CR>:'[,']norm ==<CR>
```

Comment: I think there's a small error in your first code block:
`<CR><CR>k` should be `<CR><CR><Up>`, because we are still in insert mode at that point. The mapping in the last code block has the error corrected.

Comment: @graysonwright, thank you. I have no idea how I let this one pass since I used the correct `<Up>` in the mapping version. Oh well…

Comment: No worries! Thanks for your solution, I'm using it myself!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @romainl is very complete.

But if you are new to vim I recommand to only goes on line you want to reformat (everywhere on it), and then in normal mode :

```
:s/,/,\r/g
```

It should be enough at the beginning.